# Pass two variables in anchor link

Tags: asp.net, anchor, href

having the following anchor tag, I would like to pass one variable for use in the redirect form. As you see I have here the destination url and the name of the link. I'm using Request["changeId"] for get it in the form.

```
<td class="id"><a href='/workplace/managechange?ChangeId=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "aux_RelatedChangeID.Id")%>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "aux_customChangeId")%></a></td>
```

1. Can I pass another variable to the form, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "aux_approvalID")%>, and get it via Request?
2. Has this variable to be visible in the url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT will not be possible to hide a parameter using a get request / link, if you used a form post then it would be 'hidden' from the user.

This would require either...

```
<form action="/workplace/managechange" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ChangeId"  value="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "aux_RelatedChangeID.Id")%>" /> 

<input type="hidden" name="approvalID" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "aux_approvalId")%>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Values" />
</form>
```

Or doing this by AJAX potentially.

Do you need to pass both variables , could you not derive it when the managechange page / action is called?

Also why do you need to hide this item from the query string?

It is already public and from looking at the query string it is not seo'd, so that woudl not appear to be a reason either.

Regards

Steve

Comment: Thanks Steve, now I see more clear my options. I was trying to pass two variables for avoid do a query in the destination. I didn't want show everything in the url because this sometimes will look a very large url. I'm going to try with form post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my first question:

```
<td class="id"><a href='/workplace/managechange?ChangeId=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "aux_RelatedChangeID.Id")%>&approvalID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "aux_approvalId")%>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "aux_customChangeId")%></a></td>
```

And I'm thinking will not be possible hide it in the url, right?

Comment: You can 'hide' it if required, though unless SEO is a concern then I would not worry about having a long URL. There are a couple methods you can use. Either A) Url rewriting - I use this successfully in a number of my old webforms sites (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module). B) Use routing, my recommended approach - used by default in MVC and available in .NET 4.0 and above for webforms as well (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx)